# Convert BIGINT UNSIGNED to INT

Tags: mysql, types, casting

I know it is unorthodox and potentially dangerous to want to convert something from a larger to a smaller sized data type. However, in this case, it is extremely unlikely that the value of the `BIGINT UNSIGNED` column is ever larger than the maximum size of an `INT` column.

So, using MySQL, I'm reading the table structure. While reading the `information_schema.columns.ordinal_position` column, I realized that it is of type `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. Now, I want this as an `INT` instead for my processing purposes. I want to cast/convert the type in SQL.

`CAST` and `CONVERT` only allow me to change the sign of the data type, apparently.

```
SELECT CAST(ordinal_position AS SIGNED)
FROM information_schema.columns
```

I want the column specifically returned as an `INT`. E.g. chop the column at the maximum value of an `INT` and return that value.

For now I will just change the datatype after I pull the value back. But I'd like to know how to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[this article](http://www.ehow.com/how_7593959_convert-bigint-int.html) seems to have a solution:

> Create the function that will perform the conversion:
>
> CREATE FUNCTION BigToInt (n BIGINT) RETURNS INTEGER RETURN n;
>
> As you can see, the function is very short and simple: It takes a
>   BIGINT and immediately returns it as an ordinary integer. However, one
>   consequence of this is that some of the data will be truncated down to
>   the largest possible value for Int.

(presumably you can add "UNSIGNED" to the signature - if not you can still combine it with the cast you already have that removes the unsigned part).

Comment: What's the alternative way to do it without creating a function? Having to remember to teardown the function after use is a bother.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to create the function that way, you will get this error:

```
ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL,
or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
(you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators
variable)
```

See this link for details on how to resolve it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html

Comment: In this particular case the fix is to add `DETERMINISTIC`.

Answer (score -1):

I unfortunately did not have the right to create functions on the DB where I was working, so after trying a few things this worked:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name INTEGER;
```

Saved me having to rewrite 15 foreign keys.