# Mysql bigint to int

Tags: mysql, function, int, bigint

Anybody knows how to convert a big int to int in a MySQL stored procedure.

1. Solution in this posthttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595217/convert-bigint-unsigned-to-int is not working as I tried:

set @x=BigToInt(2147483649);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column

2. I tried this and it doesn't work either:

   DELIMITER //
   DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS BigToInt;

   CREATE FUNCTION BigToInt (n BIGINT) RETURNS INTEGER
   begin
       DECLARE result INTEGER default 0;
       set result = CAST(n as SIGNED);
       return result;
   end//
   DELIMITER ;

it gives me same error as #1.

Comment: What part of "Out of range value for column" is a problem here? `INT` can *only* hold values between -2147483648 and 2147483647. 2147483649 is **too big**. If you need numbers that big you need a `BIGINT`, there is no way around it.

Comment: Unless, *maybe*, `INT UNSIGNED` is suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION BigToInt (n BIGINT) RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
begin 
DECLARE result VARCHAR(50) default 0; 
set result = CAST(n as signed);
return result;
end
// DELIMITER ;
```

This will accept a long int but limit to 19 value only.

Integer has a [maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171312/what-is-the-max-number-if-i-store-int255-in-mysql)